# owl carousel image not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            items: 4,
            navigation: true,
            mouseDrag: false
        });
    });
```

```html
<div id="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl4.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  
</div>
```

image not displaying properly Owl carousel not working as expected. I have uploaded three images and when I click on the second image, half of the image is shown. When I click on the last image, nothing is shown(blank).

I am using owl carousel script v.1.3.3

Please, any help would be appreciated.
[image: main-image][image: 1st-image-clicked][image: 3rd-image-clicked][image: 4th-image-clicked]

Comment: you know that owl carousel is at version 2.3.4? Any reason not to upgrade?

Comment: I had thought about that. However, this isn't my personal project; rather a group project and they chose to stay on v.1.3.3

Comment: Besides the version number. I still believe there should be a fix around this though.